# Make Cocoa app stay on top of fullscreen apps

Tags: macos, cocoa, fullscreen

I'm working on an app that has a status menu and from that menu user can open the app's main window. I want the ability to open this window on top of the full screen apps. The following code works fine if **Application is agent (UIElement)** is set to **YES**:

```
- (IBAction)showMainWindow:(id)sender
{
   [_window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
   [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
```

However, I want to have an icon in the dock as well. If **Application is agent (UIElement)** is set to **NO** showMainWindow causes the app to jump to a different space rather than appearing on top of the active full screen app. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here for the sake of completeness.

After little more research turns out there is no way around it. It just the way OS X works.

My solution: I gave user an option in app preferences whether they want the app to be a dock type app or the agent type. Set the **Application is agent (UIElement)** to **YES** in main plist. You can change the app type during runtime by setting the app activation policy to NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular.